# How to replace the string in apex?

Tags: apex

I have this 13000ed.kjhrbimil=1456ghtuiolsdjmr and I would like to just get 1456 out of this string, I have tried .replace('13000ed.kjhrbimil\=1456ghtuiolsdjmr','') but did not work out. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: I downvoted this because "it didn't work" is not a helpful statement, and the question seems to have had only the barest of effort put into it. I don't see any research attempt here.

Comment: You are right, I have not put effort into framing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are likely a number of ways to do this, but the two that come to my mind first are:

- Use `String.replace()` with a regex that has a capturing group so that when it comes to the "replace" part of that operation, you can simply use something like `'$1'` (if you have capturing groups, the `$n` syntax gives you the result of the nth capturing group, 1-indexed)
- Use `String.split()` using '=' as your delimiter to get an array of size 2. Fetch the second string in the array, and `.left(4)`

The exact approach obviously changes according to the form of the string you're working on (if you don't have an '=', then splitting on '=' makes no sense).

As a brief example of the regex solution...

```java
String givenString = 'abc+123/456';

// .* = zero or more of any character, matches the 'abc' part, and later the '/456' part
// \\+ = followed by a literal '+'
// (<stuff>) = capturing group
// \\d{3} = look for precisely 3 decimals, matches the '123' part
String just123 = givenString.replace('.*\\+(\\d{3}).*', '$1');
```